# SQL: How to find disparate values in columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle SQL table, where `product_id` 101 and 103 have disparate values in columns `attr1` and `attr3` respectively.

`data`

```
| PRODUCT_ID | ATTR1 | ATTR2 | ATTR3 |
|------------|-------|-------|-------|
| 101        | a     | x     | z     |
| 101        | a     | x     | z     |
| 101        | aa    | x     | z     |
| 102        | b     | y     | z     |
| 102        | b     | y     | z     |
| 103        | c     | z     | z     |
| 103        | c     | z     | zz    |
```

What is the most efficient way of getting an output query highlighting the disparity as shown below, given there are 7000 rows and 30 columns to check this logic for?

`output`

```
| PRODUCT_ID | DESCR            |
|------------|------------------|
| 101        | Issue with attr1 |
| 103        | Issue with attr3 |
```

`query`

```
WITH data AS (
   
   SELECT 101 product_id, 'a' attr1, 'x' attr2, 'z' attr3 FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 101 product_id, 'a' attr, 'x' attr2, 'z' attr3  FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 101 product_id, 'aa' attr, 'x' attr2, 'z' attr3  FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 102 product_id, 'b' attr, 'y' attr2, 'z' attr3  FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 102 product_id, 'b' attr, 'y' attr2, 'z' attr3  FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 103 product_id, 'c' attr, 'z' attr2, 'z' attr3  FROM dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 103 product_id, 'c' attr, 'z' attr2, 'zz' attr3  FROM dual
   
)

SELECT product_id, 'Issue with attr1' descr FROM data GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr1) > 1
UNION
SELECT product_id, 'Issue with attr2' descr FROM data GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr2) > 1
UNION
SELECT product_id, 'Issue with attr3' descr FROM data GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr3) > 1
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using aggregation which is correct, but use it correctly:

```
select product_id, 'issue with ' || regexp_replace(
    case when count(distinct attr1) > 1 then 'attr1, ' end ||
    case when count(distinct attr2) > 1 then 'attr2, ' end ||
    case when count(distinct attr3) > 1 then 'attr3, ' end, ', $', '')
from t
group by product_id
having count(distinct attr1) > 1
or     count(distinct attr2) > 1
or     count(distinct attr3) > 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the comma at the end optional, where it only shows when there are multiple issues?